Ubuntu 22.04 VM: Connect: network is unreachable (missing interface?)
I'm currently stuck with a Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS VM (on VMware Player 17 on Win 10 host) that has lost network connectivity, as main issue I've found. (The cause may be linked to a messed-up VMware tools update -- among other symptoms I can't lauch the Desktop anymore and I'm stuck with the CLI login).
After quite some research I've found a similar (but mine seems worse) question here, which I've used to collect info in the hope that the 'ask ubuntu' community can help. When looking at the network configuration content I should have, it looks like I'm missing a network interface and associated configuration ?
Also, I guess I'll have to setup a network gateway but I don't know how to identify its IP and where to configure it.
Please bare with me, I'm only a Linux amateur and my network knowledge is pretty low level. Here is the info I've collected (I've removed all comment lines)
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:ec:97:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:69:41:f6:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route show
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 

$ ping 172.17.0.1 --> works fine, but that's to the docker engine

$ ifconfig -a
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:69:41:f6:18  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0c:29:ec:97:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 80463  bytes 5725221 (5.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 80463  bytes 5725221 (5.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ ifconfig -s
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
docker0   1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo       65536    81424      0      0 0         81424      0      0      0 LRU
    
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

$ cat /etc/networks
link-local 169.254.0.0

$ cat /etc/netconfig
udp        tpi_clts      v     inet     udp     -       -
tcp        tpi_cots_ord  v     inet     tcp     -       -
udp6       tpi_clts      v     inet6    udp     -       -
tcp6       tpi_cots_ord  v     inet6    tcp     -       -
rawip      tpi_raw       -     inet      -      -       -
local      tpi_cots_ord  -     loopback  -      -       -
unix       tpi_cots_ord  -     loopback  -      -       -

$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: ubuntu-22-vm
 Pretty hostname: Ubuntu-22-VM
       Icon name: computer-vm
         Chassis: vm
      Machine ID: beaff557cde040b49a851dc496349c6d
         Boot ID: 9e1f982935244d89b74943299b8853c1
  Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 6.5.0-44-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: VMware, Inc.
  Hardware Model: VMware Virtual Platform

When logging in the CLI console I'm getting this notification:
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available: 7: /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-updates-outdated: not found
run-parts: /etc/update-mot.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 127

The VMware setup has the network configured as NAT for two VMs, and this is listed from the Windows 10 host OS (see VMnet1 and VMnet8), one for Win 11 which works fine and one for Ubuntu.
C:\ ipconfig /all
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Nexus
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : voo.be

Ethernet adapter LAN Home:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : voo.be
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-62-66-50-BE-71
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2788:1148:254:a875:f4ad:3a6c:4e6d(Preferred)
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 16 August 2024 16:05:33
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 17 August 2024 16:05:33
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2788:1148:254:e25e:9d3b:20f8:a2c2(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:2788:1148:254:a0df:6dd0:ac43:3222(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::923e:83e0:5f5:e9b8%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.9(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 16 August 2024 16:05:32
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 17 August 2024 17:23:14
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::10:18ff:fe56:f7f3%5
                                       192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 235430502
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-5B-DD-8C-08-62-66-50-BE-71
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2788:fff0:7::3
                                       2a02:2788:fff0:5::140
                                       109.88.203.3
                                       62.197.111.140
                                       2a02:2788:fff0:7::3
                                       2a02:2788:fff0:5::140
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix Search List :
                                       voo.be

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-15
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f711:99fc:9527:8f45%21(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.212.39(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 201981991
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-5B-DD-8C-08-62-66-50-BE-71
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::99a9:b4:fe7a:7756%39(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 654331990
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-5B-DD-8C-08-62-66-50-BE-71
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cdb3:ae94:897d:d823%40(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.88.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 671109206
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-5B-DD-8C-08-62-66-50-BE-71
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-62-21-20-8F-EF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-F0-40-AD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::301f:2b5f:a34f:2312%35(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.18.144.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 587208029
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-5B-DD-8C-08-62-66-50-BE-71
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

I can mount an USB drive and use this mean to import/export files if necessary.
Using this, I've imported the latest open-vm-tools (open-vm-tools-12.4.5-23787635.tar.gz) from the Github and tried to install it but the configure process fails during the initial checks with: configure: error: mspack >= 0.0.20040308alpha is required  but correcting this requires downloading patches.
As another issue (is it a side-effect?) the services apt-news and esm-cache services required by the 'Pro' version of Ubuntu for live patching can not be started but... their respective '.service' unit files can not be found (!).
To provide full context, I started debugging this situation by creating this fist question: Ubuntu 22.04 VM starts with CLI instead of desktop likely after former update failure. I've created this thread to focus on the netwok connectivity issue.
Your advice will be greatly appreciated in resolving my situation, at least by restoring network conectivity ! Thanks a million :-)
